# Error when using dplyr rename_at and stringr str_replace together to rename columns

Tags: r, tidyverse, stringr

I want to rename a couple of variables that have a certain prefix using str_replace.
I am running into the issue depicted with the REPREX bellow:

```
test <- tibble::tribble(~pre_a, ~pre_b, ~c,
                       1,2,3,
                       4,5,6)
test %>%dplyr::rename_at(., dplyr::vars(starts_with('pre')), 
                         stringr::str_replace(., pattern = 'pre', replacement ='PRE'))
```

error:

> Error in get(.x, .env, mode = "function") :    object 'c(1, 4)' of
> mode 'function' was not found In addition: Warning message: In
> stri_replace_first_regex(string, pattern,
> fix_replacement(replacement),  :   argument is not an atomic vector;
> coercing

The issue is solely with str_replace, because if I a base R function it will work:

```
test %>%dplyr::rename_at(., dplyr::vars(starts_with('pre')), toupper)
```

Note: I don't just want to convert to uppercase, so I need to use the str_replace function.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use the `~` notation when using a custom function.

```
library(dplyr)

test %>% 
  dplyr::rename_at(dplyr::vars(starts_with('pre')), 
                  ~stringr::str_replace(., pattern = 'pre', replacement ='PRE'))
```

Also `rename_at` is now replaced with `rename_with`.

```
test %>% 
  dplyr::rename_with(~stringr::str_replace(.,pattern = 'pre',replacement ='PRE'),
                     dplyr::starts_with('pre'))

# A tibble: 2 x 3
#  PRE_a PRE_b     c
#  <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>
#1     1     2     3
#2     4     5     6
```