# Why does combination of rename_with() and str_replace() fail?

Tags: r, dplyr

I am trying to replace "Abundance." in the names of the columns in my tibble. I am using the following approach:

[Error when using dplyr rename_at and stringr str_replace together to rename columns](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69028606/error-when-using-dplyr-rename-at-and-stringr-str-replace-together-to-rename-colu)

```
xx <- structure(list(Sequence = c("HSEAATAQR", "GAAAHPDSEEQQQR"), Abundance..126 = c(12.3, 12.2), Abundance..127N = c(17.7, 13.5), Abundance..127C = c(11.9, 11.3)), row.names = 1:2, class = "data.frame") 
rename_with(xx, str_replace(., pattern = "Abundance.", replacement = ""), contains("Abundance."))
```

I get the error: "Error in vctrs::vec_size_common(string = string, pattern = pattern, replacement = replacement,  :
object '.' not found"

I understand that it means that the str_replace() function does not receive the string argument that I am trying to pass to it as ".", but it does seem to work in the example mentioned above

[Error when using dplyr rename_at and stringr str_replace together to rename columns](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69028606/error-when-using-dplyr-rename-at-and-stringr-str-replace-together-to-rename-colu)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are missing a `~`operator. Use the following

```
xx %>% 
  rename_with(~str_replace(., pattern = "Abundance.", replacement = ""), contains("Abundance."))
```

The functions argument must be either

- a named function (e.g. a function defined before, see example later)
- an anonymous function (like `\(x) str_replace(x, pattern = "Ab", "")`)
- or a formula (indicated by `~`)

##### Named Functions

To use `rename_with` with a **named function**, you might use the following:

```
delete_abundance <- function(x) {
  str_replace(x, pattern = "Abundance.", replacement = "")
}

xx %>%
  rename_with(delete_abundance, contains("Abundance."))
```

Answer (score 1):

```
library(tidyverse)
```

Alternative 1:

```
xx %>% 
  rename_with(~ str_replace(.x, pattern = "Abundance.", replacement = ""),
              contains("Abundance."))
```

Alternative 2:

```
xx %>% 
  rename_with(~ str_remove(.x, "Abundance.."),
              contains("Abundance.."))
```